# How can I compare a two digit month variable with a single digit month variable?

Tags: sql-server-2008, casting, datepart

Here is what I have:

```
select case when cast(datepart(mm, enrollments.enddate) as varchar)<cast(datepart(mm, getdate()) as varchar)
            then 'Expired'
            when cast(datepart(m, enrollments.enddate) as varchar)=cast(datepart(m, getdate()) as varchar)
            then 'Renewal required by end of this month'
            when cast(datepart(m, enrollments.enddate) as varchar)-1=cast(datepart(m, getdate()) as varchar)
            then 'Renewal required by end of next month'
            when cast(datepart(m, enrollments.enddate) as varchar)>cast(datepart(m, getdate()) as varchar)
            then 'Current'
            Else null
         End) as [Certification Status]
```

All logics work except for the first one in which when 12 for the month of the enrollments.enddate is compared to the getdate month 3, result shows that 12<3 leading to the output 'Expired' instead of 12>3 'Current'

Using SQL Server 2008

[image: Results - Records incorrectly marked Expired]

Comment: Stop casting as VARCHAR, and use the numeric value instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing the comparisons as strings instead of number?  If you want strings, why use `datepart()` instead of `datename()`?

So:

```
select (case when datepart(month, enrollments.enddat) < datepart(month, getdate())
             then 'Expired'
             when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate) = datepart(month, getdate())
             then 'Renewal required by end of this month'
             when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate) - 1 = datepart(month, getdate())
             then 'Renewal required by end of next month'
             when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate) as > datepart(month, getdate()
             then 'Current'
        End) as [Certification Status]
```

Notes:

- Use `month` instead of `m` or `mm` for `datepart()`.  `month` is unambiguous and clear both to you and to other who might be reading the code.
- Use `datename()` if you want a string and `datepart()` if you want a number.